# Using addEventListener and scrollTo to drag through a div

Tags: javascript

Here is some working JS that lets you mousedown and drag the body instead of scrolling.

https://codepen.io/JTParrett/pen/rkofB?editors=0011

```
var curYPos = 0,
curXPos = 0,
curDown = false;

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){ 
if(curDown === true){
window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollLeft + (curXPos - e.pageX), document.body.scrollTop + (curYPos - e.pageY));
}
});
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){ curDown = true; curYPos = e.pageY; curXPos = e.pageX; });
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){ curDown = false; });
```

I'm trying to get this to work except instead of the entire body, I just have one small div in the body that I want to be able to drag around.
Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to target that div instead of the body.

Thanks in advance :-)